# How to make large WCF services with many functions importable into VS 2010?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, mex

I've got a large class with many functions exposed as a WCF service, which also has a mex endpiont. Now, when I'm trying to add a reference to that service in Visual Studio 2010, I'm getting following error:

[image: mex error]

Is there anything I can do, besides cutting back on the method count, to make this error disappear?

Here's the code I'm using for the mex endpoint:

```
        // Check to see if the service host already has a ServiceMetadataBehavior
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = svh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
        // If not, add one
        if (smb == null)
            smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        //smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        svh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        // Add MEX endpoint
        svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
          ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
          MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(),
          location+"/mex"
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override this with the maxNameTableCharCount attribute on the readerQuota node in your config file.

Here is the <readerQuote> documenation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325.aspx

This is an example of the auto-generated client side configuration. The default value is 16384.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="YOUR_NAME" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="268438456" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="268438456"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="YOUR_ADDRESS" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="YOUR_ENDPOINT" contract="YOUR_CONTRACT"
        name="YOUR_NAME" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: is this server side? can you provide code example on how to do this?

Comment: see update for the mex endpoint code. I looked at the client app.config, and it indeed contains readerQuotas node, but no maxNameTableCharCount attributes

Comment: this is the one that I'm using <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />, still getting the error, and the service isn't THAT big

Comment: @ArsenZahray Example added. This particular example is using basicHttpBinding so modify as needed.